# Symfony2 - how do I find template from Symfony debug toolbar?

Tags: debugging, symfony, toolbar

I'd like to see what twig templates were used to render the current page.

Does the Symfony debug toolbar already do this and I'm missing it?  The request panel comes close.

Yes, I know I can look it up in the controller, but then it can be overridden and etc.  I'd like to know what actually happened.

If it's not already there, how could this be done?